# Perl script gives different results for HTTP/POST when run from command line and server

Tags: perl, post, cgi

I'm trying to write a proxy that takes a POST request in UTF-8, converts the request to TIS-620 (Thai language) and submits it to a server.  It then takes the TIS-620 server response and converts it to UTF-8.

The problem I'm having is that everything works fine when I run from the command line.  I get back a page of HTML as expected.  When I run the same script from my webserver I get a HTTP/200 OK response, but there's nothing in the body.

I'm absolutely stumped as to why this is happening.  I'm also at a loss as to how to go about debugging this.  Any thoughts much appreciated.

This is a stripped down version of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml -w -T
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI::Escape;
use utf8;

# Print Headers
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

my $postData = "word=กระคน";

# Convert to TIS-620
my $post = encode("iso-8859-11", "$postData");

# URI Escape it
$post = uri_escape($post, "\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff");

# Prepare POST
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $server_endpoint = "http://rirs3.royin.go.th/new-search/word-search-all-x.asp";
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);

# Set header fields and POST data
$req->header('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
my $postLength;
{use bytes; my $postLength = length($post);}
$req->header('Content-Length' => $postLength); 
$req->content($post);

# Get & print response
my $resp = $ua->request($req);
my $respCode = $resp->code();
print("Response Code =  $respCode<br>\n");
$resp = $resp->decoded_content;
my $respUTF = decode("iso-8859-11", $resp);
print ("Response:<br>\n$respUTF\n");
```

The script can be run at http://thai-notes.com/cgi-bin/test2.pl

Comment: You were a little too aggressive with your stripping down the code, and you took out [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).  I suggest edit your question by adding that back with all your [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) declarations.  ;)

Comment: Done.  No errors found.  Still works differently from command line and from server.

Comment: I've duplicated your code on Apache 2.0.65, and it works the same as console.  Therefore, there is something specific to your server that is the issue.  I would try turning your output into valid HTML first, as it's possible that the server is filtering for some reason.  If that doesn't work, definitely try sharing your server information in this question and of course check the error log for any obvious clues.

Comment: I'm now beginning to suspect that my web hosting service doesn't have mod_proxy enabled.  They don't provide telnet access so I can't check.  Waiting to hear back from them.  Returning HTTP/200 with no content is apparently the correct response to unsupported proxy requests.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if my mod_proxy theory makes sense.  Are cgi script HTTP requests mediated by Apache? Or are they made direct, bypassing the server?

Comment: mod_proxy is apparently enabled.  Not sure where to go next.

Comment: Finally, it turns out the problem wasn't with my code, or with the server.  It appears that certain versions of Microsoft IIS return the content-length, but not the actual content when using Dynamic IP Restrictions.  The bug was reportedly fixed in version 7, but reintroduced in version 8.

Comment: On a separate note, wouldn't $postLength always have 0 value as you're have different scope on the next line?